# stop listening when moving to another page

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to leave the page when listening is stopped.

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference myRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_showcomments);


}




    private void callFireBase()
        {
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
            myRef.child(id).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Toast.makeText(showcomments.this, "" + dataSnapshot.child("comment").getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(showcomments.this, "hey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            myRef.removeEventListener(firebaseDatabase);
        }
```

when I go to another page I come out of the application I want to stop listening I tried a lot and searched for themes on the same site but not found nothing useful

Comment: This line of code doesn't even look like it should compile: `myRef.removeEventListener(firebaseDatabase);`  You can't pass an instance of FirebaseDatabase to that method.  It takes an event listener.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `ChildEventListener` into your `Activity` then remove it when going out of `Activity`.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ChildEventListener {

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_showcomments);
    }

    private void callFireBase() {
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        myRef = myRef.child(id);
        myRef.addChildEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myRef.removeEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Toast.makeText(showcomments.this, "" + dataSnapshot.child("comment").getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(showcomments.this, "hey",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Please do like this and save your `DatabaseReference` accordingly from which you want to `removeListener`

Comment: he keeps kicking me when I leave and return again